# How to load a URL in chromium?

Tags: android, browser, chromium

I created a new activity which extends `SingleTabActivity` and it calls:

```
getActivityTab().loadUrl(new LoadUrlParams("http://google.com.vn", PageTransition.AUTO_TOPLEVEL));
```

But nothing is showing up. Do I need anything else to tell Chromium to render web content?

Thank you!

Comment: share your activity here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Override finishNativeInitialization and add following lines:

```
LayoutManager layoutDriver = new CustomTabLayoutManager(getCompositorViewHolder());
    initializeCompositorContent(layoutDriver, findViewById(org.chromium.chrome.R.id.url_bar),
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            (ToolbarControlContainer) findViewById(org.chromium.chrome.R.id.control_container));
```